# How to restrict selection on the datatable row?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, selection, webix

I want to disable a datatable row. In such case I see two required steps:

- set CSS
- prevent selection

I've successfully done the first step with corresponding Webix methods:

```
function disableRow(table, row){
  table.addRowCss(row, "disabled-row")
};

webix.ui({
  view:"datatable",
  id:"mytest",
  ...
}); 

disableRow($$("mytest"), 2)
```

http://webix.com/snippet/e47b4257

But how can I restrict the selection of this row? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer you are looking for [here](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.datatable_disabled_config.html)

> There's no `disabled` property for rows, but you can use onBeforeSelect and onBeforeEditStart events to prevent related actions on the particular row:

There is a link to [this](http://webix.com/snippet/2dd1a299) snippet on the above linked page which does what you are looking for.

```
webix.ui({
    view:"datatable", autoConfig:true, editable:true, data:grid_data,
        on:{
            onBeforeEditStart:function(id){
                if (id.row == 2 ) return false
            },
            onBeforeSelect:function(id){
                if (id.row == 2 ) return false
            } 
        }
});
```

Comment: Please add the body of your answer to this post, this is not helpful if the linked pages are moved or go down. Please see the FAQ on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there might not be a built in way to disable a row. I did come across [this](http://webix.com/snippet/2dd1a299) snippet that might help

I've tried programatically selecting the row afterwards and it won't let you.

```
webix.ui({
  view:"datatable", id:"abc",autoConfig:true, editable:true, data:grid_data,
  on:{
    onBeforeEditStart:function(id){
      if (id.row == 2 ) return false
    },
    onBeforeSelect:function(id){
     if (id.row == 2 ) return false
    }
  }
});

$$("abc").select(2);
alert($$("abc").getSelectedId())
$$("abc").select(3);
alert($$("abc").getSelectedId())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` to override the table styles:

```
<style>
 .disabled-row {
   background-color: #ddd !important;
   color: #aaa !important;
 }
</style>
```

http://webix.com/snippet/1a3569c6

Comment: Yep, but even now the row is still can be selected programmatically: http://webix.com/snippet/21a310f5

Answer (score 0):

To disable any feature provided by webix, you can override its events and handle the same:
like to stop the selection on any particular column, row or cell you can override `onBeforeSelect` and return false for that specific row/column/cell.

There are events for everything i.e `onBeforeSelect,onAfterSelect,onBeforeEditStop, onAfterEditStop` etc.